# Specifying filename in os.system call from python

Tags: python, os.system

I am creating a simple file in python to reorganize some text data I grabbed from a website. I put the data in a .txt file and then want to use the "tail" command to get rid of the first 5 lines. I'm able to make this work for a simple filename shown below, but when I try to change the filename (to what I'd actually like it to be) I get an error. My code:

```
start = 2010
end = 2010
for i in range(start,end+1)
    year = str(i)

  ...write data to a file called file...

    teamname=open(file).readline() # want to use this in the new filename
    teamfname=teamname.replace(" ","") #getting rid of spaces

    file2 = "gotdata2_"+year+".txt"
    os.system("tail -n +5 gotdata_"+year+".txt > "+file2)
```

The above code works as intended, creating file, then creating file2 that excludes the first 5 lines of file. However, when I change the name of file2 to be:

```
file2 = teamfname+"_"+year+".txt"
```

I get the error:

sh: line 1: _2010.txt: command not found

It's as if the end of my file2 statement is getting chopped off and the .txt part isn't being recognized. In this case, my code outputs a file but is missing the _2010.txt at the end. I've double checked that both year and teamfname are strings. I've also tried it with and without spaces in the teamfname string. I get the same error when I try to include a os.system mv statement that would rename the file to what I want it to be, so there must be something wrong with my understanding of how to specify the string here.

Does anyone have any ideas about what causes this? I haven't been able to find a solution, but I've found this problem difficult to search for.

Comment: First, have you tried `print` out what `file2` is—and, for that matter, what the whole command-line string is? It's a lot easier than trying to guess what it must be based on a third-hand error from the shell.

Comment: Second, why are you using `os.system` in the first place? [The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.system) explicitly tells you that `subprocess` is easier and more powerful. In particular, `subprocess` lets you pass a list of arguments instead of trying to figure out how to quote spaces and escape quotes and deal with special characters and so on—in other words, exactly what you're facing here.

Comment: @abarnert I don't think the docs say anything about `subprocess` being easier - else they would be lying. I love Python with all my heart, but the `subprocess` APIs (sic) are not its strong point. Still, `os.system` is a no-go of course.

Comment: @LukasGraf: They say "using that module is preferable to using this function". Follow the link and see for yourself.

Comment: Yeah, and it is (and I did). But `'preferrable' != 'easier'`.

Comment: Don't get my wrong - I don't use `os.system`, and I replace almost every use of it I see in code. Using `subprocess` is way more powerful, flexible and safe. But easier? Nope, no way.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Easier than some of the nice modules on PyPI? No. Easier than using `bash` instead of Python? No. Easier than using `os.system` (or its equivalents in C, perl, etc.)? Definitely. Quoting things for the shell is hard. (Unless you're using Python 3.3+ and POSIX, in which case [`shlex.quote`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex#shlex.quote) is the answer.) When you don't need the shell, using it makes things harder for yourself. And this question is itself a perfect example of that.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what your actual strings are, it's impossible to be sure what the problem is. However, it's almost certainly something to do with failing to properly quote and/or escape arguments for the command line.

My first guess would be that you have a newline in the middle of your filename, and the shell is truncating the command at the newline. But I wouldn't bet too heavily on that. If you actually printed out the repr of the pathname, I could tell you for sure. But why go through all this headache?

The solution to almost any problem with `os.system` is to not use `os.system`.

If you look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.system), they even tell you this:

> The [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; **using that module is preferable to using this function.** See the [*Replacing Older Functions with the `subprocess` Module*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section in the `subprocess` documentation for some helpful recipes.

If you use `subprocess` instead of `os.system`, you can avoid the shell entirely. You can also pass arguments as a list instead of trying to figure out how to quote them and escape them properly. Which would completely avoid the exact problem you're having.

For example, if you do this:

```
file2 = "gotdata2_"+year+".txt"
with open(file2, 'wb') as f:
    subprocess.check_call(['tail', '-n', '+5', "gotdata_"+year+".txt"], stdout=f)
```

Then, if you change that first line to this:

```
file2 = teamfname+"_"+year+".txt"
```

It will still work even if `teamfname` has a space or a quote or another special character in it.

---

That being said, I'm not sure why you want to use `tail` in the first place. You can skip the first 5 lines just as easily directly in Python.